# How to change size of database

Tags: c#

I know how to change size database on SQL (in SQL Server 2005 Express Edition)

```
ALTER DATABASE Accounting
MODIFY FILE
(NAME = 'Accounting',
SIZE = 25)
```

How to change size database useing C#?

Answer (score 3):

Submit the DDL via an `ExecuteNonQuery` command:

```
mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();

mySqlCommand.CommandText =
  "ALTER DATABASE Accounting MODIFY FILE (NAME = 'Accounting', SIZE = 25) ";

mySqlConnection.Open();
int result = mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
mySqlConnection.Close();
```

Similar examples can be found here (showing issues related to snapshot isolation, but the ideais basically the same):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Following example will give you a better overview. Having defined parameters you can pass some stuff that not necessary has to be static. Using `using` will make sure everything is disposed/closed properly (and or reused if necessary).

```
     public const string sqlDataConnectionDetails = "Data Source=YOUR-SERVER;Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=YourUserName;Password=YourPassword";

     public static void ChangeDatabaseSize(int databaseSize) {
        const string preparedCommand = @"
                        ALTER DATABASE Accounting
                        MODIFY FILE
                        (NAME = 'Accounting', SIZE = @size)
                        ";
        using (var varConnection = SqlConnectOneTime(sqlDataConnectionDetails))
        using (SqlCommand sqlWrite = new SqlCommand(preparedCommand, varConnection)) {
            sqlWrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", databaseSize);
            sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

This is supporting method that makes it easy to establish connection everytime you want to write/read something to database.

```
    public static SqlConnection SqlConnectOneTime(string varSqlConnectionDetails) {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(varSqlConnectionDetails);
        try {
            sqlConnection.Open();
        } catch {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(new Form {
                                                               TopMost = true
                                                           }, "No connection to database. Do you want to retry?", "No connection (000001)", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            if (result == DialogResult.No) {
                if (Application.MessageLoop) {
                    // Use this since we are a WinForms app
                    Application.Exit();
                } else {
                    // Use this since we are a console app
                    Environment.Exit(1);
                }
            } else {
                sqlConnection = SqlConnectOneTime(varSqlConnectionDetails);
            }
        }
        return sqlConnection;
    }
```